# How to isolate firebase variable from browser console

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm working on a project using firebase services and I realize that the `firebase` variable (or object, not so sure) is accessible from console of the Chrome. This will cause some security issues, which lead user to sabotage my app like adding data/deleting data that not supposed to be happen. I believe this can happen not only on firebase variable, but also any other variable (in general).

[image: Chrome Console]

I've been reading articles about IIFE, but on this case is not working and making firebase still available. My question is, How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attackers can access the firebase variable from the console, but you can set up security rules to keep your database safe. There is a video on this topic that Fireship made on youtube => [click here](https://youtu.be/b7PUm7LmAOw)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm looking for another possible answer as well

Answer (score 1):

Attackers will be not able to write data if you will set up security rules. It's available for both Firestore and Realtime Databases and for Storage.
Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics

You can restrict access to DB with next lines:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

But if you want to restrict to several fields - you can restrict access to defined properties. Also, you're able to restrict access for not authorised users.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow public read access, but only content owners can write
    match /some_collection/{document} {
      allow read: if true
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author_uid;
      allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.author_uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Also, you can write unit tests for rules to test if they work correctly.

And many-many more

Comment: Appreciate the answer